# "Yours sincerely" or "faithfully" if I address the name of a company?

Tags: formality, letter-writing

When I write a formal letter to a company or so, I usually go with "Dear *Company Name*" instead of "Dear Sir/Madam". In these cases should I end my letter with "Yours sincerely" or "Yours faithfully"?

(I've always solved it by using more general endings, like "Regards". I am really interested which one would be correct, though.)

Comment: "Dear Acme Corp" is equivalent to "Dear Sirs" (which I would say is actually preferable), so the nominated duplicate answers this.

Comment: In the US, promising faithfulness to a complete stranger would mark the letter as BS. You can be sincere, you can be thankful, you can wish them well, but loyalty (okay, a formality) says love bombing.

Comment: @YosefBaskin - So what is the traditional usage with 'Dear Sir' in the US? _Yours truly_, as one answer to the duplicate question suggests?

Comment: We have short attention spans here. Seriously. By the time we get to the ending, we have no idea where you started. But still a keen ear for hogwash. If you don't know my name and address me as my company, *faithfully* is presumptuous. Never heard it. Less is more. Thank you. Sincerely. Yours truly. Yours. All the best. Let me know, please. Looking forward to doing business with you.